# FreeBSD - get timezone in Continent/Region format

Tags: bash, shell, freebsd, date

I have a Linux (bash) script to generate a login message (motd). One of the things it displays is the timezone, using the command `timedatectl | grep Time | awk {'print $3'}`.
The command returns something like `America/Chicago` which is the format I am seeking.

Naturally, since there is no `timedatectl` under FreeBSD, this command does not work and I am seeking an alternative.

The closest I have managed is using `date +'%z %Z'`, but that is still quite different.

Is there a way to display the system's timezone in `Continent/Region` format under FreeBSD?

Thanks!

Comment: Does the file `/var/db/zoneinfo` exist on the system?

Comment: No, it does not. I've also sought out `/etc/timezone` which is also missing

Comment: Does `/etc/localtime` exist?

Comment: It does, but it is a binary file

Comment: `cd /usr/share/zoneinfo && find . -type f -exec cmp -s /etc/localtime '{}' \; -print | sed -e 's|^\./||' -e '/posix/d'`

Comment: Works perfectly. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This command will provide what you are looking for:

```
cd /usr/share/zoneinfo && find . -type f -exec cmp -s /etc/localtime '{}' \; -print | sed -e 's|^\./||' -e '/posix/d'
```

Output (I'm in the US on the East Coast):

America/New_York

Comment: Good stuff, +1.  A slight edit to get rid of the possibly annoying `cd` component: `find /usr/share/zoneinfo  -type f -exec cmp -s /etc/localtime '{}' \; -print | sed -e 's|^/usr/share/zoneinfo/||' -e '/posix/d'`